# square of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T(x, y) = (-x, y)$
What is $T^2$?

I've been told it's $T^2 = (-x, -y)$ but that doesn't make sense to me.
I'll be glad for a clarification.

Comment: $T^2(x,y) = T(T(x,y)) = T(-x,y) = (-(-x),y)$. I suppose it should have been $T(x,y) = (-y,x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$T^{2}(x,y) = T(T(x,y)) = T(-x,y) = (x,y)$. Hence $T^{2} = Id$. The one who told you that probably meant $T(x,y) = (y,-x)$.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, $T^2$ denotes $T\circ T$, so in this case, it would be $$(T\circ T)(x,y) = T(T(x,y)) = T(-x,y)=T(x,y)$$
So it would be $T^2 = \mathrm{id}$.

Answer (score 1):

ok let us answer it using linear algebra,what should be matrix which transforms  from $(x,y)$ to $(-x,y)$?

clearly it is

```
A=[-1 0;0 1]

A =

    -1     0
     0     1
```

what is square of this matrix?

let us do it using matlab  too,let us check that it transforms  $(x,y)$ to $(-x,y)$

```
>>  syms x y
>> A*[x;y]

ans =

 -x
  y
```

now calculate   power of matrix

```
A*A

ans =

     1     0
     0     1
```

and finally

```
(A*A)*[x ;y]

ans =

 x
 y
```